# Get Select value from dropdown in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS and can't seem to be able to make this one work:

HTML code:

```
<select name="colors">
        <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var select = document.getElementsByName("colors")[0];
console.log(select.value); // ==> it should output selected color but is not.
```

Comment: When do you run that logic?

Comment: Your code works. However, I suspect the problem is how you are using it. Are you just running that code on page load? If you are running it on page load, the value at that time is being saved. You will need to run it after some kind of triggering event, like when a button is clicked, form submitted, select is changed etc..

Comment: ^^ I agree.  Which is why I suspect if you made a change of say `<option value="blue" checked>Blue</option>` or selected (i forget which), you would probably start seeing a value

Comment: Do need to access the options before the user interacts with them? If that is the case you might want to add them programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't post the full code, I'd suppose that you're running your `JS` code before the `select` element is being loaded (if your script is in the `head`section for example).

Anyway, I'll provide some work arounds for this purpose and at the end of the answer I'll show you how to get the selected value whenever the selected item from the list has changed.

1. encapsulate your code in `load` event of the `window` :

```html
<!-- just to simulate when your JS is placed in the head section -->
<script>
  // attach a "load" event listener to the "window"
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    // select the "select" element
    var select = document.getElementsByName("colors")[0];
    // log its initial selected value. Here as we didn't explicitly assign the "selected" attribute to an "option", the first "option" value will be printed.
    console.log(select.value);
  });
</script>

<select name="colors">
  <!-- for demonstration, I changed the value to some string rather than an empty one so we could know something has been printed in the "console" -->
  <option value="acting like Im empty :)">--Please choose an option--</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

2. place your code just before the `body` closing tag hence no need to listen for the `load` event

```js
var select = document.getElementsByName("colors")[0];
// log its initial selected value. Here as we didn't explicitly assign the "selected" attribute to an "option", the first "option" value will be printed.
console.log(select.value);
```

```html
<select name="colors">
  <!-- for demonstration, I changed the value to some string rather than an empty one so we could know something has been printed in the "console" -->
  <option value="acting like Im empty :)">--Please choose an option--</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

Anyway I think that your final goal is to get the selected value whenever the selected item is being changed :

```js
// select the "select" element
var select = document.getElementsByName("colors")[0];

// attach a "change" event listener to the "select" element
select.addEventListener('change', () => {
  // log the selected value whenever it changes
  console.log(select.value);
});
```

```html
<p>choose an option from the list first</p>

<select name="colors">
  <!-- for demonstration, I changed the value to some string rather than an empty one so we could know something has been printed in the "console" -->
  <option value="acting like Im empty :)">--Please choose an option--</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

> BTW, I don't recommend selecting elements based on their `name` attributes, using `class`es or `ID`s (if the element is unique in the page or has unique functionnality) would be a better choice.

> Also, using `getElementsBy*` (Element`s` not just Elment) methods is not recommended in most situations, `querySelector` or `getElementById`(for unique elments) is better.

Comment: thx man. i guess my triggering event wasn't working

Comment: @EdwardCasanova I kenw it ! Your aim is to get the selected value when the user selects another item in the dropdown and that's what the 3rd snippet does. Anyway, glad I'd managed to help you and feel free for any further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a id of that value then use const example = document.getElementById("id")

the var should be changed to const;
and the name is the string not the value
and always use id;

Comment: I would recommend not always using ID. In many cases it will work but IDs tend to lend themselves to code that is difficult to scale. However, using classes is actually very scalable and yet still perfectly understandable and usable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```js
function  myFunction(){
         var e = document.getElementById("MySelectOption");
         var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
         console.log(strUser);
         }
```

```html
<select id="MySelectOption" name="colors" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: thx man. i guess my triggering event wasn't working.

Comment: Hey @EdwardCasanova If really this answer is useful to you then please upvote the answer :).

Comment: yeap i've tried but it says that because of my low reputation i can't change it